# Download speed slows dramatically after downloading a couple files in Java

Tags: java, networking, download, wget

I'm trying to download data from the SEC. I download them locally, upload them to Amazon S3, and then delete the files locally. The files range around 10-100MB. After a couple files are downloaded, the download speed dramatically slows down.

Here's an example of the output I have. Please ignore the `190 of 5761` stuff; I'm starting it from 189 so the previous entries don't download. So what happens here is that the process starts up and downloads 3 files, about 112 MB total, at high speed. Then subsequently it only downloads at 2-3 MB/s and never returns to the original fast speed (even after 20+ more files, which is the longest I've left it running). I included the upload speeds as well - those don't seem to be degrading, not sure if that's relevant.

```
        Downloading via wget: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961220.nc.tar.gz
        Elapsed: 0.934
        Size was 33 MB. Avg speed was 26 MB/s. 
        Finished uploading. Speed was 32 MB/s.
Downloading 190 of 5761: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961223.nc.tar.gz (current total: 33 MB; average speed: 14 MB/s)
        Downloading via wget: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961223.nc.tar.gz
        Elapsed: 1.523
        Size was 41 MB. Avg speed was 26 MB/s.
        Finished uploading. Speed was 59 MB/s.
Downloading 191 of 5761: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961224.nc.tar.gz (current total: 74 MB; average speed: 16 MB/s)
        Downloading via wget: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961224.nc.tar.gz
        Elapsed: 0.479
        Size was 38 MB. Avg speed was 79 MB/s.
        Finished uploading. Speed was 63 MB/s.
Downloading 192 of 5761: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961226.nc.tar.gz (current total: 112 MB; average speed: 20 MB/s)
        Downloading via wget: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961226.nc.tar.gz
        Elapsed: 3.859
        Size was 10 MB. Avg speed was 2 MB/s.
        Finished uploading. Speed was 37 MB/s.
Downloading 193 of 5761: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961227.nc.tar.gz (current total: 122 MB; average speed: 12 MB/s)
        Downloading via wget: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/Feed/1996/QTR4/19961227.nc.tar.gz
        Elapsed: 8.327
        Size was 30 MB. Avg speed was 3 MB/s.
        Finished uploading. Speed was 55 MB/s.
```

Extra info:

- I'm pretty sure it's not rate limiting on the server, because when I run a separate `wget` from command line on a URL that's currently being downloaded, the download is fast
- I'm not keeping these files in memory.
- I've run several times and this behavior happens consistently after 2-10 fast downloads.
- I delete the files immediately after uploading them to a separate server.
- CPU and Memory usage don't spike as the process runs.
- The actual files/URLs seem irrelevant: I can start the downloading at any index (instead of 189) and the behavior is the same.
- I'm running this on Amazon EC2 with a fresh install + OpenJDK 1.8.

I have tried two different implementations of file downloading, but both versions have the same issue. Here are my download implementations. You can see specifically from the wget implementation that this bottleneck is occurring in the single `wget` process, since the `Elapsed: __` time is increasing after the download speed drop.

Downloading with Apache `FileUtils`

```
public static File downloadFileFromURL(String tmpPrefix, String url) throws IOException {
    File tmp = File.createTempFile(tmpPrefix, null);
    tmp.deleteOnExit();
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

Downloading by invoking `wget`

```
public static File downloadFileFromURLViaWget(String url) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("\tDownloading via wget: " + url);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"wget", "-nv", url});
    pr.waitFor();
    System.out.println("\tElapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0);
    String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    File f = new File(fileName);
    f.deleteOnExit();
    return f;
}
```

I'd really appreciate any insights on this. I've searched around but haven't found any other posts about this problem.

Comment: When you say you dont think its a rate limit issue - out of curiosity are you using their API and comparing that with wget or is it FileUtils vs. wget?

Comment: They don't have an API, it's just a site designed to be easily scraped. So all I have is a bunch of URLs that lead directly to files. The version of my Java code I'm running right now literally just creates a `wget` process, but it starts slowing down. In the meantime, I can call `wget` on another screen in the same machine and it downloads at a normal fast speed. As far as I know it's impossible for the server to tell what process is calling, only that my IP is requesting data. So since one `wget` is fast while the others from the same machine are slow, I don't think it's rate limiting.

Comment: That was rambly. To clarify: my code uses `wget` to download. It slows down after a couple `wget`s. But while my code runs, I can manually do a `wget` on the same URL and it's fast.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you for clarification. Are you running these jobs in a threaded manor or in a queue like in a for loop?

Comment: For loop / queue. I'm iterating URLs one by one. For each URL, I download the file, upload it to S3, and delete the file.

Comment: So there is a lot that I can't see, but at a high level. (1) You may want to try using threads, something like this may help: https://dzone.com/articles/java-thread-tutorial-creating-threads-and-multithr And also, keep in mind if you are executing wget and comparing it to downloading a file, pushing to an s3 bucket and then purging that most certainly wont be an apples to apples, but again try threading for this. Additionally, implementing an asynchronous strategy *may* also help..